# Parse HTML titles

Tags: html, perl

```
...
<div class="termContainer">
<h4>SUMMER 2013</h4>
<ul>
<li>   
<a href="url" title="A">
<span>A</span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="url" title="B">
<span>B</span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="url" title="C">
<span>C</span>
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
<div class="termContainer">
<h4>SPRING 2013</h4>
...other links
</div>
...
```

I am writing a perl script to get the titles of links inside

```
<div class="termContainer">
```

in the HTML code above. My expected results are A, B, C.

I don't really know how to approach it. Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

Comment: HTLM::TreeBuilder::XPath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;

my $html = <<EOFHTML;
...
<div class="termContainer">
<h4>SUMMER 2013</h4>
<ul>
<li>   
<a href="url" title="A">
<span>A</span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="url" title="B">
<span>B</span>
</a></li>
<li><a href="url" title="C">
<span>C</span>
</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
...
<div class="termContainer">
<h4>SPRING 2013</h4>
...other links
</div>
...
EOFHTML

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content($html);

foreach my $title ( $tree->findvalues('//div[@class="termContainer"]//a/@title') ) {
    print $title, "\n";
}
```

Comment: I have this error '\div[@cl...
^^^
Invalid query somewhere around here (I think)'. Any idea?

Comment: shouldn't it be `//div[@class="termContainer"]/a\@title` ?

Comment: This is the error when I change the function to your way @mirod '//div[@class="termContainer"]/a\@title...
..............................^^^
Invalid query somewhere around here (I think)'

Comment: @novo, that's what I get for not testing the code :--( It should be `//div[@class="termContainer"]//a/@title` . You should learn a bit about XPath if you want to extract data from XML or HTML, it's pretty useful.